# How to place a WebBrowser control from the toolbox in a Windows Forms App designer of Visual Studio 2022

Tags: vb.net, controls, webbrowser-control, visual-studio-2022

I installed Visual Studio 2022 and followed a tutorial of VB.NET which requires that I use the toolbox to insert a WebBrowser control in the form of my Windows Forms App project. However the control was not available, after some research i tried to "right-click > Show All" on the toolbox area and then the WebBrowser control appeared in the list. but it was greyed as a non-usable control.

How can I unlock the WebBrowser feature ?

NOTE : the below code manages to insert a WebBrowser control in the Form at the "load" event. So the feature is still usable apparently...

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim WebBrowser1 As New WebBrowser With
    {
        .Location = New Point(10, 10)
    }
    Controls.Add(WebBrowser1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably going to get corrected on this I'm guessing.  But anyway my feeling is you're probably going to want to find a more up to date tutorial.  I believe the WebBrowser control has been obsoleted for some time and superseded by WebView

Comment: You probably built a .Net 5+ Project instead of a .Net Framework Project. Using the former, the WebBrowser Control is not available in the Designer. You can of course add the WebView2 Package in .Net 5+ and drop it on a Form from the ToolBox. Or build a .Net Framework Project instead.

Comment: I forgot to mention that a version of WebView2 is also available for .Net Framework. You should use this new Control instead of the old WebBrowser Control. IE is no longer supported. The Control still works, but you have to tweak it a lot to make it work with current Web Sites. -- Unless you just need it to show HTML content you have  written...

Comment: Thank you Hursey and Jimi.

@Jimi Both of your solutions are working !
1. I went to "Project > Manage NuGet Packages..." then I "Browse" tab searched "WebView2" and installed the package. Now I am able to drag the WebView2 control :)

2. I just created a Windows form App (.NET Framework) project and the WebBrowser control was available !

Thank you very much !

Answer (score -1):

1-Add WebView2 Nuget package to your project

2-Add Webview2 control to your form from toolbox

3- use it as follow:

```
webView21.Source = new Uri("https://www.google.com")
```